# Undo git update-index --skip-worktree

Tags: git, undo

A while ago I did this to ignore changes to a file tracked by git:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file>
```

Now I actually want to commit changes to that file to source. How do I undo the effects of `skip-worktree`?

Comment: I'm also interested how to get list of files in 'skip-worktree' state?

Comment: @troex https://stackoverflow.com/q/42363881/1615903

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Aha! I simply want:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file>
```

Comment: how/where is the config file for it stored?

Answer (score 43):

According to http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html, use

`git ls-files -v`

to see the "assume unchanged" and "skip-worktree" files marked with a special letter. The "skip-worktree" files are marked with `S`.

**Edit**: As [@amacleod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447862/amacleod) mentioned, making an alias to list all the hidden files is a nice trick to have so that you don't need to remember it. I use `alias hidden="git ls-files -v | grep '^S'"` in my .bash_profile. It works great!

Comment: Neat. I can use `git ls-files -v | grep '^S'` to list just files that I've "hidden" with skip-worktree. 

Hoped to make an alias "hidden" for that command, but putting a pipe redirection in the alias did not seem to work.

Comment: @amacleod use a `!`. Like this `[alias] ignored = !git ls-files -v | grep "^S"` Tested, works.

Comment: @amacleod Don't suppose you'd be able to suggest an alternative command for Windows?

Comment: @SteveChambers, Short of installing `grep`, I don't know. Depends on your shell, I guess. Git Bash does come with `grep`, I think.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @amacleod - just wasn't in my path. The only thing I needed to change for this to work on Windows was the quote style - `'` didn't work but `"` did, i.e. `git ls-files -v | grep "^S"`

Answer (score 35):

If you want to undo all files that was applied skip worktree, you can use the following command:

```
git ls-files -v | grep -i ^S | cut -c 3- | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 git update-index --no-skip-worktree
```

1. `git ls-files -v` will print all files with their status
2. `grep -i ^S` will filter files and select only skip worktree (S) or skip worktree and assume unchanged (s), -i means ignore case sensitive
3. `cut -c 3-` will remove status and leave only paths, cutting from the 3-rd character to the end
4. `tr '\012' '\000'` will replace end of line character (\012) to zero character (\000)
5. `xargs -0 git update-index --no-skip-worktree` will pass all paths separated by zero character to `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` to undo

Answer (score 14):

For all of you that love Bash aliases, here is my set to rule them all(based on C0DEF52)

```
alias gitskip='git update-index --skip-worktree ' #path to file(s)
alias gitlistskiped='git ls-files -v | grep ^S'
alias gitunskip='git update-index --no-skip-worktree ' #path to file(s)
alias gitunskipall='git ls-files -v | grep -i ^S | cut -c 3- | tr ''\\012'' ''\\000'' | xargs -0 git update-index --no-skip-worktree'
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on @GuidC0DE answer, here's a version for Powershell (I use [posh-git](http://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/))

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree $(git ls-files -v | sls -pattern "^S"| %{$_.Line.Substring(2)})
```

And for reference also the opposite command to hide the files:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree $(git ls-files --modified)
```

Answer (score 7):

For those using Tortoise Git:

1. Right click on the folder or on the specific file, then choose `TortoiseGit > Check for modifications`
2. Only check `Show ignore local changes flagged files`. You should see the file that you ignored (or all the files you've ignored, if you've right clicked on the folder)
3. Right click on the file and choose `Unflag as skip-worktree and assume-unchanged`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is aimed at less technical people using Windows.

If you don't remember/know which files you clicked "skip-worktree" on then use:

```
git ls-files -v             //This will list all files, you are looking for the ones with an S at the beginning of the line. 

git ls-files -v | grep "S " //Use this to show only the lines of interest. Those are the files that have "skip-worktree".
```

**To fix your problem:**

You can go to the files -> right click -> restore to a previous version -> click the "git" tab on top -> uncheck the "skip-worktree" checkbox -> click "Apply" at the bottom.

If the files are too many to fix by hand then you'll need to refer to the other answers.

Comment: Please clarify if you are using tortoise git or?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about tortoise git.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a PowerShell user, here's some functions (aliases) inspired by @yossico's bash aliases

```
<#
Command: gitskipped
Description: List skipped files in git
Usage: gitskipped
#>
function gitskipped {
  (git ls-files -v $args) -split "\r\n" | Select-String -Pattern '^S ' | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output $_.Line.Substring(2)
  }
}


<#
Command: gitskip
Description: Mark file(s) as "skip-worktree" in git
Usage: gitskip .env
#>
function gitskip {
  git update-index --skip-worktree $args
}


<#
Command: gitunskip
Description: Unmark file(s) as "skip-worktree" in git
Usage: gitunskip .env
#>
function gitunskip {
  git update-index --no-skip-worktree $args
}


<#
Command: gitunskipall
Description: Unmark all skipped files in git
Usage: gitunskipall
#>
function gitunskipall {
  $files = @((git ls-files -v $args) -split "\r\n" | Select-String -Pattern '^S ' | ForEach-Object { $_.Line.Substring(2) })
  git update-index --no-skip-worktree $files
}
```