# How to list files ignored with 'skip-worktree'

Tags: git

I have used `git update-index --skip-worktree <file>` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/1615903) to make git ignore local changes to a tracked file. But now I have forgotten which files I have applied it to. How can I list all files that have skip-worktree flag applied to them?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use the following command if on *nix (Linux, Mac):

```
git ls-files -v . | grep ^S
```

or, if on Windows, you can use:

```
git ls-files -v . | findstr "^S"
```

Explanation:
`git ls-files .` lists all files in the repo (assuming you are in the root folder). `-v` makes the output verbose, meaning that it will abbreviate the file status with a letter in front of the filename. The options are:

> H cached
>
> S skip-worktree
>
> M unmerged
>
> R removed/deleted
>
> C modified/changed
>
> K to be killed
>
> ? other

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt-H)

So, to only list files with `skip-worktree` flag, the output is piped to grep with `^S` as argument, meaning that only lines beginning with S are listed.

Comment: When using fish shell, you'll have to enclose the argument for grep in quotes (`git ls-files -v | grep '^S'`) because in fish shell the caret has special meaning (redirect `stderr`).

Comment: For me on Git bash capital S is showing no result but small s works.

Comment: Along the same idea, but for Windows, using powershell, use this:

`git ls-files -v . | select-string -pattern ^S`

Comment: Using Cmder or  Git Bash for Windows: `git ls-files -v | grep "^S"`

Comment: For windows plain command line: `git ls-files -v . | findstr "^S"`

Comment: Excellent answer, but the manual strangely marks `-t/-v/-f` as semi-deprecated options. Yet, this answer provides the only way I can find to list skipped files. Is there a more canonical answer to this question, or is the semi-deprecated note in the manual for other functionalities than this?

Answer (score 8):

For those using Tortoise Git, right click on the folder and choose `TortoiseGit > Check for modifications`, then only check `Show ignore local changes flagged files`.

If you want to stop ignoring a file, right click on it and choose `Unflag as skip-worktree and assume-unchanged`.