# Cannot interact with com.apple.quarantine'd file with Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, xattr

I have a file, abc.bin

```
~ ls -al
...
-rw-r--r--@    1 username  groupname    285342 Jul 23 14:45 abc.bin
...
```

I see that it has the apple @ additional metadata things

```
~ ls -l@
-rw-r--r--@    1 username  groupname    285342 Jul 23 14:45 abc.bin
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms         212 
    com.apple.quarantine          58
```

But I cannot do anything with it:

```
~ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine abc.bin
xattr: No such file: abc.bin
~ sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine abc.bin
Password:
xattr: No such file: abc.bin
~ chmod +wrx abc.bin                      
chmod: abc.bin: No such file or directory
~ rm abc.bin
rm: abc.bin: No such file or directory
~ cp abc.bin asdf.txt
cp: abc.bin: No such file or directory
~ mv abc.bin zyx.bin
mv: rename abc.bin to zyx.bin: No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? Why can I see this file but not interact with it? How do I fix this?

Comment: I found a workaround, which is to do everything through Finder, which for some reason works. It does seem extremely strange that Finder is more powerful than sudo, but I guess that's how things are? Leaving this question open in case somebody can explain what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: The "No such file or directory" errors indicate this wasn't a permissions problem or anything like that, but that the filename was wrong. It probably contained hidden/invisible characters, like maybe spaces or tabs or a carriage return at the end.

Comment: Interesting, that's something I should have thought to try. Tab completion found the file but eg "rm ab[tab]" apparently did not fill in a correctly-escaped filename. I'll see if I can replicate that. Thank you!

Comment: If you can create another file the same way (with the same problem), another method is to drag the file from the Finder into a Terminal window, and that should fill in a properly-escaped filename. But there are some invisible characters that might not show up even then (because they don't need escaping). If that doesn't make the problem apparent, run the `xxd` command (hex dump), drag in the file from the Finder, then press Return and Control-D, and see what it prints (it'll have escapes on certain characters, and a newline at the end from the Return, but look for other weird characters).

Comment: Wildcards like `ls -l abc*` may let you generate the proper filename as a command line arg.  Like `mv abc* abc.bin`.  Or `find -inum ... -exec something {} \;` using the inode number from `ls -li` if you can't find a glob expression that selects exactly that file and don't want to move aside other files with similar names