# git ignored file preventing switching branch

Tags: git

I got the impression that any ignored files are irrelevant in a git repo. But I ran into the situation below:

The .vs folder is listed in .gitignore:

```
$ cat .gitignore
.git/
.vs/
bin/
My Project/
obj/
packages/
App_Data/
```

But when I tried to switch to another branch, a file in .vs folder is blocking:

```
$ git checkout test
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .vs/myproject/v16/.suo
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

And git will complain if I tried to add this file:

```
$ git add .vs/myproject/v16/.suo
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.vs
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

And advise is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should just reindex files, try rm .git/index
git reset
git add .
git commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: If I were you, I would just `git reset HEAD~1 --hard` and forget about it

Answer (score 0):

Ignored files are untracked, and `git checkout` will not overwrite untracked files. This is a safety thing to avoid permanently deleting content.

You can force the checkout with `-f`...

> -f, --force
>
> When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs
> from HEAD, and ***even if there are untracked files in the way***. This is used to
> throw away local changes and any untracked files or directories that are in the
> way.

Or, since it will be overwritten by the checkout anyway, you can delete the offending file then checkout.

I'd recommend deleting the file because its specific to one file, while `-f` could overwrite more content.

Answer (score 0):

Let git untrack files and folders listed in .gitignore, and remember to commit to let it take effect.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Remove ignored files"
```

details

[How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore/19095988#19095988)

[git rm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505362/git-switch-branches-with-changed-skip-worktree-file)

Answer (score 0):

As you have added `.vs/` to `.gitignore` but it is still in git cache. To get out of this situation. You have to remove it from the cache and then try changing the branch.

Please follow the below steps:

```
git rm -r --cached .vs
```

If it shows new changes being added to `.gitignore` then commit those changes and change the branch otherwise just change the branch and it will be all fine.

```
git checkout test
```