# How to git stash a file mentioned in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file `.vscode/settings.json` that's listed under `.gitignore`. Thus `git stash` will skip stashing it. This causes the following error when I check out another branch

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .vscode/settings.json
```

This happens even if I issue `git stash --all`. Even if I temporarily comment out the file path in `.gitignore`, this seems to not work since stashing will also stash the change to `.gitigore`, thereby nullifying the commenting out.

Why isn't `git stash --all` ignoring the `.gitignore` file? What's the best way to stash a `gitignored` file?

Comment: "Ignored" means "not under Git's control". Git is essentially blind to the existence of this file. It makes no sense to speak of stashing such a file. A stash is a commit; you've told Git _ not_ to commit this file.

Comment: You could say `git stash push -- myfile` but then only this one file would be stashed. Still, perhaps that would do. But it sounds like what's really needed is to get clear on your policy towards this file. Needing to stash an ignored file seems like a misunderstanding.

Comment: The error message you're getting indocates that `.vscode/settings.json` is *tracked*, and a tracked file is never ignored, regardless of whether it's listed in `.gitignore`. I think you're asking [this Frequently Asked Git Question](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F).

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I did `git update-index --skip-worktree .vscode/settings.json` at one point. [Undoing this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131197/undo-git-update-index-skip-worktree) revealed the file under `git status -uno`.